# C# - Nested usercontrols within tablelayoutpanels (sizing problems)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, nested, tablelayoutpanel

Well it's kinda hard to explain for me, but here is a graphic:

[image]

I do have three user controls binded in a form. Each of them has more or less the same structure: a set of data which is described in the header, seperated by a splitcontainer (visualised by the red line) and a tablelayoutpanel with one row at default.

In the tablelayoutpanel should be other controls, each of the three classes (specimen, block & procedure) do have a child attribute of the underlying class. 
One Specimen can have one or more blocks, which can have one or more procedures. 
It's a typical tree structure or one of these russian matryoshka dolls.
I just need to populate all the controls in there accurate structure.

The data which I retrieve is saved on a database-server, the user inputs some number and in return the program gets a set of data with the information to build a tree of it.

Well, the logic wasn't hard to write, what bothers me is displaying the controls regardless of how complex the structure is which I retrieve.

The user controls are fixed in size at first, but they should change dynamically the more data is retrieved. I thought of something like this.

**Pseudo-Code:**

```
for each Specimen in SpecimenList 
{
    PopulateSpecimen()

    for each Block in SpecimenList[i].Child
    {
        //adding new row to tablelayoutpanel of specimen
        PopulateBlock()
        //size.height of specimen control += 20

        for each Procedure in SpecimenList[i].Child[ii].Child
        {
           //adding new row to tablelayoutpanel of block
           PopulateProcedure()
           //size.height of specimen control += 10
           //size.height of block control += 10
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that is a simplified pseudo-code version of my actual file. But I hope you do undertand what I'm trying to do.

**Now my problem is:** if I change the height of my specimen control, all underlying usercontrols change as well. Everything in it scales, but that was not my intention, I need to dynamically generate new space for the specimen control after any new block is added to the specimen control, I also need to generate space for the Block AND Specimen control for every added procedure.

I do it in C# with following command: 
`spec.Size = new Size(spec.Size.Width, spec.Size.Height + offset);`

So I want to get my specimen control to get longer in height, but without the tablelayoutpanels/other controls in it growing.

Do I forget something essential? is there a useful way to accomplish what I try to do? I have a lots of cases to visualize. 
If someone could recommend me a comfortable solution I would be grateful.

I hope I could keep my concern understandable enough.